# Handbrake Script misses TS files

Tags: handbrake, handbrakecli, handbrake-js

I'm trying to compress all the subfolders of a main file, and this is the script I run. For some reason, the folders have TS files saved with .mp4 at the end of their file name.

1. Can anyone explain why it's completely bypassing them?
2. I'm trying to make a log for my script, so it shows which files it detected, which it went through and which it skipped/returned error.
3. If anyone knows how to keep it going or skip/restart when there's an error, it'd help.

I've attached the folder with the source code: https://file.io/taFsYIKPrImh
The program is a CLI launcher and then the subfolder launcher which identifies the main root folder.

[image: main file constants.cs]